# AIR Native Process works on Mac, but not Windows

Tags: windows, flash, air

I'm building an AIR application with Flash CC, so that I can use Native Processes. Before I even got to integrating it into my full project, I created a small test project to see if it would work. I tried it in Windows and it didn't work. I switched over to Mac and got it to work there, though.

The Native Process is triggered by a key press. The file is published as a Windows installer, not an Air package. I have made sure to include extendedDesktop in the xml file. I have double checked the file paths. Are there any other reasons this wouldn't work?

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        var exe:File = new File("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");
        var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

        public function startProcess(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 65) {
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = exe;
                args.push("C:/Users/Tristan/Documents/TVCR/airTestFile.rtf");
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;
                nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Does it work in a "test movie" mode? The script seems fine so I advise doing some debugging. Make a text field to output log information, like if keypress triggers the event, and also **try** ... **catch** the **NativeProcess.start** for exceptions.

Comment: Native Processes don't work in "test movie" mode. They only work when published a s Windows installer. I'm not sure how to make a text field for log information. Could you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... You don't know how to create a **MovieClip** in the Library, how to design a **TextField** in it, how to add them to main timeline?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I don't know how to get the text field to output log information.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How to output some debug information. The following code will show some messages if the keyboard events really trigger the handler method.

```
public function startProcess(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // LogText:TextField
     LogText.appendText("\n\nKey Pressed: " + event.keyCode);
}
```

How to output and diagnose an exception:

```
try
{
    nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    LogText.appendText("\n\nThe process has been started without exceptions.");
}
catch (fail:Error)
{
    // LogText:TextField
    LogText.appendText("\n\n" + fail.getStackTrace());
}
```

Comment: This returned an answer for the keyboard event, but the try and catch arguments didn't return anything.

Comment: @browntastic Then put everything else under **try** ... **catch** blocks in order to learn where else it fails.

Comment: I get the error "1120: Access of undefined property fail." when publishing.

Comment: OK, I figured this out, and it looks like the file path is in the wrong format. I've posted an answer. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @browntastic Oh, you've figured that one out. Good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file path I was using wasn't in the correct format.

```
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
```

should be

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The file path for Windows has to use a double backslash "\" since a single backslash gets interpreted as an escape.

Something that's handy, especially if you need to build a path to an executable or your making something that's going to be Windows and Mac is to use `File.separator` since it will do "\" for Windows and "/" for Mac/Linux

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#separator